# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2+\tan \left(e^{x}-\cos x\right)-e^{x}-\cosh x}{x(\sqrt{1+2 x}-\sqrt[3]{1+3 x})}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, taylor-expansion, indeterminate-forms

Evaluate the limit $$L=\lim _{x \to 0}\frac{2+\tan \left(e^{x}-\cos x\right)-e^{x}-\cos h x}{x(\sqrt{1+2 x}-\sqrt[3]{1+3 x})}$$

By generalized binomial expansion we have

$$\sqrt{1+2 x}-\sqrt[3]{1+3 x}=\left[1+\frac{1}{2}(2 x)+\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)}{2 !}(2 x)^{2}+\cdots\right]-\left[1+\frac{1}{3}(3 x)+\frac{\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}-1\right)}{2}(3 x)^{2}+\cdots\right]$$
$\implies$
$$\sqrt{1+2x}-\sqrt[3]{1+3x}=\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)$$
$\implies$
$$L=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2+\tan \left(e^{x}-\cos x\right)-e^{x}-\cos h x}{x^{3}\left(\frac{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+O\left(x^{3}\right)}{x^{2}}\right)}$$
$\implies$
$$L=2 \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2+\tan \left(e^{x}-\cos x\right)-e^{x}-\left(\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}\right)}{x^{3}} \to (1)$$

We have $$e^{x}=1+x+\frac{1}{2} x^{2}+\frac{1}{6} x^{3}+\frac{1}{24} x^{4}+\ldots$$ and
$$\cos x=1-\frac{1}{2} x^{2}+\frac{1}{24} x^{4}-\frac{1}{720} x^{6}+.$$

Thus we have
$$e^x-\cos x=x+x^2+\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^4)$$

Now we have the Maclaurin's series expansion of $\tan x$ as:
$$\tan x=x+\frac{1}{3} x^{3}+\frac{2}{15} x^{5}+...$$
So we get

$$\tan(e^x-\cos x)=x+x^2+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{1}{3}x^3+O(x^4) \to (2)$$

Also we have
$$e^{x}+\cosh x=e^{x}+\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$$
$$e^x+\cos hx=\begin{aligned}
\frac{3}{2}(1+x+&\left.\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\frac{x^{3}}{3 !}+..\right) 
+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{x}{1 !}+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}-\frac{x^{3}}{3 !}+\cdots^{}\right)
\end{aligned}$$
$\implies$
$$e^x+\cos hx=2+x+x^2+\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^4) \to (3)$$

Using $(2),(3)$ in $(1)$ we get
$$L=\frac{2}{3}$$
Is there any alternate way?

Comment: Have you tried using L'Hopital's rule? NB: you might need to use it twice.

Comment: This looks good to me

Comment: @MichaelHartley. I think that three times would be required. Just out of curiosity, did you try to compute the successive derivatives ? They are monsters. Cheers :-)

Comment: they already have the taylor series, the derivatives can't be harder than that. They only need the derivatives at 0.

Answer (score 2):

There is one right way to do this limit:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{  
\frac{1- \cosh x}{x}+  \left[ \frac{\tan(e^x - \cos x)}{x} -\frac{1-e^x}{x} \right]}{
\sqrt{1 +2x}- (1+3x)^{\frac13}}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\left( - \frac{x}{2!} - \frac{x^3}{4!}+O(x^5)\right)+ \left[ \frac{\left(2e^x -1- \cos x  \right)+\frac{(e^x - \cos x)^3}{3}}{x}.. \right]}{\left[ 2-1\right] \frac{x^2}{2!} +O(x^3)}$$

Note that:

$$ (2e^x - 1 - \cos x)= \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + O(x^4)$$:

Hence,

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{ \left( - \frac{x}{2!} - \frac{x^3}{4!}+O(x^5) \right)+ \left[ \frac{\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + O(x^4) }{x}.\right]}{ \frac{x^2}{2!} +O(x^3)} $$

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{x^2}{3} + O(x^3)}{\frac{x^2}{2!}+O(x^3)}= \frac23$$

Idea: I first rearranged the expression to make them all look like derivatives, for the denominator I tried to find the first non zero term of in it's expansion and then expanded numerator in that.

It is still a mess, but it reduces solving the question in an algorithim.

0. Arrange the expressions to look like known limits on numerator and denominator
1. Find deg denominator
2. Expand numerator till deg denominator
3. Careful algebra
4. Take the limit